# EEG Signal Processing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, signal-processing, mne-python, eeglab

I'm reading my excel file in jupyter Notebook using MNE-python. I converted my fif file into .csv file to check it's values. After printing the first 4 columns, the output values does not match with my excel values?

[Conversion Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJqq8.png)

[Output Values:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmrWO.png)

[Original Values in excel:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BKkN.png)

```
import mne
import pandas as pd
raw = mne.io.read_raw_fif('second_dataset_raw.fif', preload=True)
csv_file_path = 'second_dataset_raw.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)
df.head(4)
```

The output does not matches with my original values in excel file. The path of file is also correct with proper name.

Comment: I think your values do match. It's just that the output from the pandas dataframe is only displaying the numbers to a certain number of decimal places.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73478223/1862861 for how to set the output display precision

Comment: @user19077881 although a CSV file is text the usual convention is that any plausible numerical value ends up as a number when it is read unless it is in string quotes. I'm with Matt here I think the OP needs to tell jupyter to display his data in the same scientific notation as Excel so that he can compare it with his original spreadsheet.